# Adding Mouse listener to multiple JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

```
for(int k=0;k< dtm.getRowCount();k++) //dtm is object of default table model
{
    if(String.valueOf(dtm.getValueAt(k,1)).equalsIgnoreCase("Today") && check==0 )
    {
        cnt++;

        JLabel jp=new JLabel();
        panel.add(jp);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        if(cnt<=12)
        {
        jp.setBounds(j,500,100,100);
        j=j+115;

                jp.addMouseListener(this);
        }
        else
        {
            j=j-115;
            jp.setBounds(j,400,100,100);
        }
        String b="<html><body text=#FDFA0B>"+String.valueOf(dtm.getValueAt(k,0))+"'s Birthday";
        jp.setText(b);
        jp.setFont(new java.awt.Font("comicbd",Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, 14));


    }
}
```

It will not work mouselister only apply for last placed Label...
I want to apply mouse listener for all label how can I do that ..
please help me ....

Comment: You should post the implementation of your MouseListener. Ideally, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

Without SSCCE I can tell you that you're adding listener on 3 conditions:

- `String.valueOf(dtm.getValueAt(k,1)).equalsIgnoreCase("Today")`
- `check == 0`
- and `if(cnt<=12)`

Other `JLabel`s (that don't pass these conditions) haven't assigned your listener.

Make sure that you're clicking correct labels.

Or move `jp.addMouseListener(this);` just after `JLabel` creation (if you want to add listener to all your `JLabel`s).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can add the same `MouseListener` to multiple components - here's an example in it's simplest form:

```
    MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Released!");}

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Pressed!");}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Exited!");}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Entered!");}

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("Clicked!");}
    };

    JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Label1");
    j1.addMouseListener(ml);
    JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Label2");
    j2.addMouseListener(ml);
```

**BUT** according to your code, you're messing with a JTable - and JTable's act differently than you're thinking.  The labels you're trying to edit are actually part of a TableCellEditor.  The JTable uses the single TableCellEditor (read: single JLabel) to display every cell in the JTable.  This is why you're only seeing the Listener applied to the last cell (because that's the only the last cell has a full component any more - the rest are just ghosts of where the component was applied before).

The good news is you can add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable`, and obtain information from there:

```
    final JTable table = new JTable();
    MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()));
        }
    };

    table.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: Actually this will not work since Renderers in JTable are not live components and you cannot add listeners to those renderers. Renderers are only used to paint themselves over given bounds. In a JTable, if you want to listen to mouse clicks/move etc... you must add the mouse listener to the JTable directly. From the mouse event and with the JTable you can find out which cell has been clicked.

Comment: Heh - as I was writing the second part of my answer, that was going through my head (but I wasn't sure, so I decided to post anyways - since I was pretty sure the code in the top portion wouldn't work in the OP's case).  +1 for you, Guillaume!

Answer (score 0):

One Option is to add another inner class:

```
     class MListener extends MouseAdapter{
         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
         //other mouse evetns
     }
```

then rather then:

```
jp.addmousListener(this);
```

do:

```
jp.addMouseListener(new MListener());
```

Comment: your solution is add multiple MouseListeners to multiple JLabels, it should work with one Listener

Comment: Lets see your solution, there is defiantly a way, this is a quick fix.